# Mostrar errores en vista Login en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, controller

Soy nuevo y no tengo mucha idea del uso de **Codeigniter**. El caso ¿Sabéis si hay alguna forma de devolver un comentario (de error) a una vista, desde el controlador, una vez habiendo hecho una consulta de un modelo?. Es decir:

1. relleno un formulario de inicio de sesión y doy a iniciar sesión
2. me lleva a un método del controller (que también es el encargado de cargar la vista, mediante `Index()`)
3. ese método llamado `login()` utiliza una devolución de una consulta recibida del modelo.
4. si la consulta me devuelve un error o un fallo porque no hay usuarios, se mete en un condicional `if()`.
5. `if($error=true){`. Aquí quiero que cargue la misma vista del mismo formulario y que le mande un $data con un mensaje.
   Y no me funciona hacer `$this->load->viene('login', $data)`
6. el fin es hacer algo visual para que se sepa que no se ha podido iniciar sesión

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el recorrido [CLICK AQUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿podrías mejorar el formato de tu pregunta? ademas de agregar el código de tu vista login, claro que se puede mostrar un error al colocar un usuario o pass incorrecto, podría darte una respuesta pero antes hace falta ver tu vista y tu controlador para el login.

Comment: falta código del controller para ver si usas `form_validation` y de la vista para ver como imprimís los campos y los errores